# Help configure cloudflare for magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cdn

I just signed up for cloudflare free plan and changed name servers to ones provided by cloudflare, and added page rules according to their recommendations.

Currently my web settings look like this:
[image: https://puu.sh/xy1un/68df614956.png]

And dns settings in cloudflare like this:
[image]

Do i need to change anything?

The reason i ask i because most of cdn set-up guides for magento teach to change skin, media and sometimes js folder to something like cdn.XXXX.cdnhostname.com, like here:
[image]

Should this be done with cloudflare too?

Comment: I have been using CloudFlare for over a year with Mce 1.9.X and never changed these settings. My site works great and loads off of CF's cached files without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to change anything on your web settings.
You can leave them as

```
{{secure_base_url}}skin/

{{secure_base_url}}media/
```

etc.